# Plotly not displaying maps correctly, duplicate legend

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

So I'm trying to display the maps correctly in plotly, but the legends are coming back out of order and the map is a little bit distorted, the only thing showing correctly is the initial map which displays correctly, I have shared my code below please let me know where I went wrong

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from urllib.request import urlopen

def generate_health_fig():
    skc = pd.DataFrame(
        ['20001', '20003', '20011',
         '20015', '20019', '20021',
         '20031', '20035', '20037',
         '20049', '20059', '20073',
         '20077', '20079', '20095',
         '20099', '20107', '20113',
         '20115', '20121', '20125',
         '20133', '20155', '20173',
         '20191', '20205', '20207'], 
        columns=['fips']
    )

    token = 'A'

    with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
        counties = json.load(response)  

    df = pd.read_csv('data/healthy-wealthy-wise-data.csv', dtype={'fips':'str'})
    df = df.sort_values(by=['healthy_quartile', 'fair_poor_quartile'])

    colorscales = [
        [(0.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,1.0)'), (1.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,1.0)')],
        [(0.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.75)'), (1.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.75)')],
        [(0.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.5)'), (1.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.5)')],
        [(0.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.25)'), (1.0, 'rgba(22,74,88,0.25)')]
    ]

    fig = go.Figure()

    health_quartile_to_z = {quartile: i for i, quartile in enumerate(df['healthy_quartile'].unique())}
    fair_poor_quartile_to_z = {quartile: i for i, quartile in enumerate(df['fair_poor_quartile'].unique())}

    # Add the first choropleth map (Health Indicator)
    for i, indicator in enumerate(['healthy_quartile', 'fair_poor_quartile']):
        for quartile in df[indicator].unique():
            dfp = df[df[indicator] == quartile]
            if indicator == 'healthy_quartile':
                z_vals = [health_quartile_to_z[quartile]] * len(dfp)  # Use health_quartile_to_z for health indicator
            else:
                z_vals = [fair_poor_quartile_to_z[quartile]] * len(dfp)  # Use fair_poor_quartile_to_z for fair/poor health
            fig.add_choroplethmapbox(
                geojson=counties,
                locations=dfp['fips'],
                z=z_vals,
                featureidkey='id',
                showlegend=True,
                name='Quartile ' + str(quartile),
                colorscale=colorscales[health_quartile_to_z[quartile]],  # Use health colorscale for health indicator
                showscale=False,
                text='County:  ' + dfp['county'].str.title() +
                     '<br>Quartile:  ' + dfp[indicator].str.split(' ').str[0],
                hoverinfo='text',
                visible=(i == 0),
            )

# Rest of the code remains the same...


    choropleth = go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=counties,
        locations=df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['fips'],
        z=df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['healthy_index'],
        zmin=df['healthy_index'].min(), zmax=df['healthy_index'].max(),
        colorscale=[[0, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'], [1, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)']],
        marker_line_color='rgb(255,193,0)',
        marker_line_width=2,
        showscale=False,
        text='County:  ' + df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['county'].str.title() +
        '<br>Quartile:  ' + df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['healthy_quartile'].str.split(' ').str[0],
        hoverinfo='text',
        visible=True
    )

    choropleth1 = go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=counties,
        locations=df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['fips'],
        z=df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['fair_poor_ind'],
        zmin=df['fair_poor_ind'].min(), zmax=df['fair_poor_ind'].max(),
        colorscale=colorscales[0],  # Use the same color scale as the first map (changed this line)
        marker_line_color='rgb(255,0,0)',
        marker_line_width=2,
        showscale=False,
        text='County:  ' + df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['county'].str.title() +
        '<br>Quartile:  ' + df[df.fips.isin(skc['fips'].tolist())]['fair_poor_quartile'].str.split(' ').str[0],
        hoverinfo='text',
        visible=False  # Set the first map as hidden initially
    )


    
    fig.add_trace(choropleth)  
    fig.add_trace(choropleth1)  



    fig.update_layout(
        legend_title='Index Performance', 
        margin={'r': 0, 't': 0, 'l': 0, 'b': 0},
        mapbox_accesstoken=token,
        mapbox=dict(style='carto-positron', zoom=6, 
                    center={'lat': 38.4937, 'lon': -98.3804})
    )

    # Add Restyle Dropdown
    dropdown_options = [
        {'label': 'Health Indicator', 'value': 'health_indicator'},
        {'label': '% Fair or Poor Health', 'value': 'fair_poor_quartile'}
    ]

    button_args = [
        dict(
            args=[{'visible': [True]*4 + [False]}],  # Show the first map (Health Indicator) and hide the second
            label='Health Indicator',
            method='update'
        ),
        dict(
            args=[{'visible': [False] + [True]*4}],  # Show the second map (% Fair or Poor Health) and hide the first
            label='% Fair or Poor Health',
            method='update'
        )
    ]

    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus=[
            go.layout.Updatemenu(
                buttons=button_args,
                direction='down',
                pad={'r': 10, 't': 10},
                showactive=True,
                x=0.99,
                xanchor='right',
                y=1.1,
                yanchor='top'
            )
        ],
        annotations=[
            dict(text='Health Indicator', showarrow=False, x=0.5, y=1.05, xref='paper', yref='paper', align='center')
        ]
    )

    return fig




# Generate the health_fig
health_fig = generate_health_fig()

# Display the figure
health_fig.show()
```

correct graph
[image]

wrong graphs

[image]

[image]

Comment: If multiple graphs are added, it is possible that the legends will overlap. Can you provide the data you are using and the correct geojson file? That way you'll have a better chance of getting an answer, and not just from me.

Comment: I can't provide the data, but if you have some pointer let me know, is it the Z value?

Comment: So, do you have any data on toys you can publish?

Comment: I have an excel file but I don't know how to add it